# Do I need to explicitly switch Paramiko or Ansible to use UTF-8 to handle non-ASCII characters in su passwords?

Tags: character-encoding, ansible, paramiko

I am fetching a database from a remote machine using this Playbook command:

```
ansible-playbook -K -vvv ansible/fetch-database.yml
```

The first part of the playbook looks like this:

```
---

- name: Set this playbook to run on the live server
  hosts: webservers
  remote_user: jon
  become_method: su
  become_user: root

  roles:
    - fetch-database
```

And the role's first task starts off with this (there are other tasks but Ansible crashes before it can get to them, so I assume they are not relevant):

```
---

- name: Install the MySQL packages to support MySQL exporting on the remote in Python
  apt: name={{ item }} state=installed update_cache=yes
  become: true
  with_items:
   - python-mysqldb
```

The purpose of this is to install a database library on the Ubuntu remote server so I can do a MySQL dump and then fetch the SQL file back to my localhost.

I am using Paramiko as the SSH driver, configured thusly in my local config `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
transport=paramiko
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jon/Development/Personal/server-build/ansible/lib/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 96, in run
    item_results = self._run_loop(items)
  File "/home/jon/Development/Personal/server-build/ansible/lib/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 252, in _run_loop
    res = self._execute(variables=task_vars)
  File "/home/jon/Development/Personal/server-build/ansible/lib/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 447, in _execute
    result = self._handler.run(task_vars=variables)
  File "/home/jon/Development/Personal/server-build/ansible/lib/ansible/plugins/action/normal.py", line 33, in run
    results = merge_hash(results, self._execute_module(tmp=tmp, task_vars=task_vars))
  File "/home/jon/Development/Personal/server-build/ansible/lib/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py", line 647, in _execute_module
    res = self._low_level_execute_command(cmd, sudoable=sudoable, in_data=in_data)
  File "/home/jon/Development/Personal/server-build/ansible/lib/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py", line 721, in _low_level_execute_command
    rc, stdout, stderr = self._connection.exec_command(cmd, in_data=in_data, sudoable=sudoable)
  File "/home/jon/Development/Personal/server-build/ansible/lib/ansible/plugins/connection/paramiko_ssh.py", line 311, in exec_command
    chan.sendall(self._play_context.become_pass + '\n')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 797, in sendall
    sent = self.send(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 729, in send
    m.add_string(s[:size])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/message.py", line 259, in add_string
    self.packet.write(s)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

fatal: [server.example.com]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
```

It looks like my root password is being passed as ASCII, and it seems to be struggling on a pound sign (£). I should think this is the main error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

I guess that this is a bug (since it is not well handled) but I can't imagine that no-one has spotted this before. Thus, I would assume that there is some option to pass this password over UTF-8 - if so, how can I do that?

I am using the current `devel` branch of Ansible from GitHub, hash `46a97e1f551`. I would guess that this issue would be affected by the submodules in use, so for completeness, they are as follows:

```
 1d0d5db97a26fefc5ce462ef5fac84086122bbe3 lib/ansible/modules/core (heads/devel-165-g1d0d5db)
 00b8b96906a741afa8eaa1245d0e229f099318a5 lib/ansible/modules/extras (heads/devel-116-g00b8b96)
```

I don't imagine it matters too much, since it feels like a Python issue or a config issue, but the local and remote machines are both Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Ansible is running on Python2 which has pretty awful Unicode handling (hence the big break to 3) so I'd be surprised if there's any workaround to this. You're probably best off raising this as an issue on their Github.

Comment: Alright @ydaetskcoR, I'll do that - thanks. Odd though, I can't imagine I am the first person to use non-ASCII password characters with Paramiko. I am using the version in the Ubuntu 14.04 repo, so maybe that's an old one. Is it simple to load using a Python dep manager? I guess that would be `pip`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is to disable Paramiko and use the default SSH transport mechanism. This previously did not work, and hung on commands requiring `su`, which is why I swapped to Paramiko in the first place. However that problem seems to have been recently fixed.

A bug report for the Paramiko issue [is here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16557).

Comment: Paramiko is used if the version of OpenSSH connection settings lack "ControlPersist" option, which allows persistent SSH connections and makes ansible work smoothly by eliminating SSH connection overhead. RHEL6 required Paramiko, but not RHEL7.